# How could I update my a specific value in a array of json, which depends on values in other json while allowing it to be able to edit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

not so sure how to put it in a clean way, I try to summarize it by cases to illustrate the problem.

At first by default, my product list has a default product with expiry date:2030

```
 const productListdemo = {
    Category_A: [{ productName: "defaultProduct", expiryYear: 2030 }],
  };
```

In case 1:

When I add a new product, the default product expiry date will align with newly added

```
For example:  (from 2030 to 2020)
productList = {
  Category_A: [
    { productName: "defaultProduct", expiryYear: 2020 },
  ],
  Category_B: [
    { productName: "sausage", expiryYear: 2020 },
  ],
};
```

In case 2:

When there is a newly added product with largest expiry date, the default product should update and follow it.(from 2020 to 2040)

```
productList = {
  Category_A: [
    { productName: "defaultProduct", expiryYear: 2040 },
  ],
  Category_B: [
    { productName: "sausage", expiryYear: 2020 },
     { productName: "meat", expiryYear: 2040 },
  ],
};
```

In case 3: ( suppose from 2040 to 2050)
But when I update my default Product, it should be able to adjust to foward years (only larger than the currect expiryYear, says in the previous example, >2040 ) But now it is fixed (always 2040). How could I alter my update function to fix this bug?

Here is my update function

```
useEffect(() => {
    let longestExpiryYear = 0;
    Object.entries(productList).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      // console.log(key)
      // console.log(value)
      value.forEach((product) => {
        if (product.productName === "defaultProduct") {
          return;
        } else
          longestExpiryYear = Math.max(longestExpiryYear, product.expiryYear);
      });
    });

    if (longestExpiryYear) {
      setProductList((pre) => {
        const posOfDefaultProduct = pre["Category_A"]
          .map((val) => val.productName)
          .indexOf("defaultProduct");
        // console.log('posOfDefaultProduct: '+ posOfDefaultProduct)
        pre["Category_A"][posOfDefaultProduct].expiryYear = longestExpiryYear;

        return pre;
      });
    }
  }, [productList]);
```

Full code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const productListdemo = {
    Category_A: [{ productName: "defaultProduct", expiryYear: 2020 }],
  };

  const [productList, setProductList] = useState(productListdemo);
  const addFirstProduct = () => {
    const product = {
      Category_B: [{ productName: "sausage", expiryYear: 2030 }],
    };
    setProductList((pre) => {
      return { ...pre, ...product };
    });
  };
  const addSecondProduct = () => {
    const product = {
      Category_B: [
        { productName: "sausage", expiryYear: 2020 },
        { productName: "meat", expiryYear: 2040 },
      ],
    };
    setProductList((pre) => {
      return { ...pre, ...product };
    });
  };

  const editDefaultProduct = () =>{
    console.log('asdsad')
    setProductList((pre) => {
      const posOfDefaultProduct = pre["Category_A"]
        .map((val) => val.productName)
        .indexOf("defaultProduct");
      // console.log('posOfDefaultProduct: '+ posOfDefaultProduct)
      pre["Category_A"][posOfDefaultProduct].expiryYear = 2050;

      return {...pre};
    });
  }

  const showProductList = () =>{
    console.log(productList)
  }
  // update default product expiry year after updateding product list
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('edit happening')
    let longestExpiryYear = 0;
    Object.entries(productList).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      // console.log(key)
      // console.log(value)
      value.forEach((product) => {
        if (product.productName === "defaultProduct") {
          return;
        } else
          longestExpiryYear = Math.max(longestExpiryYear, product.expiryYear);
      });
    });

    if (longestExpiryYear) {
      setProductList((pre) => {
        const posOfDefaultProduct = pre["Category_A"]
          .map((val) => val.productName)
          .indexOf("defaultProduct");
        // console.log('posOfDefaultProduct: '+ posOfDefaultProduct)
        pre["Category_A"][posOfDefaultProduct].expiryYear = longestExpiryYear;

        return pre;
      });
    }
  }, [productList]);

  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <button onClick={addFirstProduct}>add first product</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={addSecondProduct}>add second product</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={editDefaultProduct}>Edit Default Product expiry year to 2050</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={showProductList}>show product list </button>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't buy sausages from you! :P ;)

Comment: for eating or for what ?

Comment: If you just update the expiry date on your previous sausages when new ones arrive ;) Just a joke, but also a comment towards the logic ;)

Comment: system should do the expiry date update automatically when newly added with largest expiry date too.

Comment: it is fun tho. if i change it to longer expiry date , would you buy it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional condition in your editDefaultProduct function to check if the new expiry year is greater than the current value before updating it. Here's the updated code:

```
const editDefaultProduct = () => {
  setProductList((pre) => {
    const posOfDefaultProduct = pre["Category_A"]
      .map((val) => val.productName)
      .indexOf("defaultProduct");
    if (pre["Category_A"][posOfDefaultProduct].expiryYear < 2050) {
      pre["Category_A"][posOfDefaultProduct].expiryYear = 2050;
    }
    return { ...pre };
  });
};
```

Comment: if i edit default goal to say 2020( in the example, it is 2050), then it will not update to 2020 in this  changed function. because at the start, i have a default year, 2030. @Sang Nguyen